# MPMoviePlayerController currentPlaybackTime and initialPlaybackTime don't work at all

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've been trying to set the starting point for an `H264` encoded video using the following properties:

```
self.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime = 5;
self.moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = 5;
```

before or after calling `play` or `prepareToPlay` methods of `MPMoviePlayerController` but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Overall `MPMoviePlayerController` seems to be an exclusively buggy API, I'm surprised to see something like this from Apple.

What is the best replacement for it on iOS 7-8?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38671351/6656894 see my answer

Comment: If you want to replace MPMoviePlayerController with something else use AVPlayerViewController. It is not deprecated and if you will set initial playback time for the AVPlayer it will work correctly (instead of the MPMoviePlayerController).